# Passing a function to Enum.map in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm learning Elixir and I wonder if there is a better way to pass a function pointer to Enum.map. I have this code:

```
defmodule MyModule do

    defp greet(person) do
        IO.puts "Hello " <> person
    end

    def main() do
        people = ["Manuel Bartual", "El hijo de la Tomasa"]
        Enum.map(people, &greet/1)
    end

end
```

It works fine, but I wonder if there is another way to do this instead of using `&greet/1`

Comment: What’s wrong with `&greet/1` (which is apparently _the best feature of Elixir ever_, according to José)? In other words, what do you want it to look like? `Enum.map(people, fn person -> IO.puts "Hello " <> person end)` would do, for instance. `Enum.map(people, &greet(&1))` would do as well.

Comment: Actually, it's ok but I just want to know if this is the idiomatic way. I have just started with Elixir.

Comment: It depends. If the only purpose of existence of private function `MyModule.greet/1` is to be used as mapper, I would go with bare `fn person -> ... end`.

Comment: Understood, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More idiomatic would be:

```
def main do
  ["Manuel Bartual", "El hijo de la Tomasa"]
  |> Enum.map(&greet/1)
end
```

1. You [should not use parentheses](https://github.com/christopheradams/elixir_style_guide#fun-def-parentheses) when no arguments are required in the function.
2. The [pipeline operator](https://github.com/christopheradams/elixir_style_guide#pipe-operator) (`|>`) is one of the most idiomatic Elixir features. It says, take the result that was just evaluated and call the following function passing that result as the first argument.